# Building a link to download ebooks directly from a website to Apple's iBooks Application

Tags: iphone, ipad, webkit, mobile-safari, mobile-webkit

[PragmaticProgrammers](http://pragprog.com/frequently-asked-questions/ebooks/ipad-how-to) states the following on their website:

> Jan 11, 2011 Note: Apple has made it
>   possible to download ebooks directly
>   in to iBooks in the latest release of iOS.
>   This week we updated our online store
>   to support this—visit either the
>   regular or cut-down mobile versions of
>   our site on an iPhone or iPad. When
>   you click a download link for an epub,
>   your device will pop up an Apple
>   dialog offering to load it into iBooks
>   (or any other appropriate
>   application). Your iPhone or iPad will
>   need to be up-to-date for this to
>   work.

I searched on Apple's developer website and couldn't find any hint on how to build this. Does anyone here now how this works? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything to "build" (except for your epub file..)  Have you tried downloading an epub book from the net?  It works for me, that is, when I click an epub link in Mobile Safari on my iPhone, iOS offers to download it into iBooks.

Here's a free epub that I found on the web, which works fine.

http://bobdc.s3.amazonaws.com/books/epubkidsbooks/LittleBoPeep-ANurseryRhymePictureBook.epub

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer...i didn't see the wood for the trees. ;-)